# Python error on GAE with Memcache - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a small Python app that produces a form, the user enters some strings in and it collects them as an array and adds (or tries to) that array as a value of a key in Google's Memcache.

This is the script:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import memcache


MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/get" method="post">
      <div><input name="ID"/></div>
      <div><input name="param1"/></div>
      <div><input name="param2"/></div>
      <div><input name="param3"/></div>
      <div><input name="param4"/></div>
      <div><input name="param5"/></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Change Status"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)

class status(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        paramarray= (self.request.get_all('param1'),
                     self.request.get_all('param2'),
                     self.request.get_all('param3'),
                     self.request.get_all('param4'),
                     self.request.get_all('param5'))
        array1 = tuple(paramarray)

        memcache.add(key=(self.request.get_all('ID')), value=array1, time=3600)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/get', status),
], debug=True)
```

I've tried setting `paramarray` as a tuple, not a list. Still getting the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gtech-iot/1.391041688070473184/main.py", line 41, in post
    memcache.add(key=(self.request.get_all('ID')), value=array1, time=3600)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 785, in add
    namespace=namespace)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 868, in _set_with_policy
    rpc = self._set_multi_async_with_policy(policy, {key: value},
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Tried to set curly braces, regular, squared, with or without the `array1=..` statement

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `list` - returned by `self.request.get_all('ID')` as the `key` argument to `memcache.add()`, which is not OK.

I'd suggest some sanity checking of the key - you want it to be at least a non-empty string to make some sense as a memcache key.

If indeed you have multiple possible 'ID' values in the request maybe concatenate them in a string (I'd still question the usability since it's not guaranteed they'd be returned in the same order at the next request) and if not then maybe use `self.request.get('ID')` instead - it won't return a list like `self.request.get_all('ID')`.

Comment: Dan, you are a genius! I was so obsessed with `paramarray` and if THAT is a list or not that I didn't even think of the ID. How did you come up with it? Is it indicated in the error message? As a follow-up, when I print the `paramarray` I get `([u'111'], [u'111'], [u'111'], [u'11111'], [u'111'])` but on the web console for App Engine Memcache, I find the key but it's value is `�(]qX111qa]qX111qa]qX111qa]qX11111qa]q X111q
atq.`. What is going on here?

Comment: I'm used to getting the most out of error msgs and stack traces :) In this case it was obvious: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` and the 1st arg to `memcache.add` was `self.request.get_all()`. Even if not obvious, my 1st debug attempt would be to display the values (and, if needed, the types) of the args passed to the upset library call - which would also show the issue. About the memcache values, the web console displays them "raw", which in your case is a _serialized_ tuple of 5 lists of unicode values. When you call memcache.get() the value is de-serialized to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the value (array1) you are storing into Memcache but rather with the key. You cannot use a value of type list as a key. Check Python Memcache API [documentaion](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache).

> Any method that takes a ‘key’ argument will accept that key as a
>   string (unicode or not) or a tuple of (hash_value, string) where the
>   hash_value, normally used for sharding onto a memcache instance, is
>   instead ignored, as Google App Engine deals with the sharding
>   transparently.